# How to pass list of tensors as a input to the graph in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am passing my input to tensors using a `tf.placeholder()` of shape `[None, None, 10]`. Now I want to iterate over the first dimension of the input, and apply some function to each slice in that dimension. However, when I try to do this using a Python `for` loop, I get an error saying that `Tensor` objects are "not iterable".

Is there any way I can pass the input as the list of tensors of shape `[None, 10]`, and how could I assign this list to the placeholder? Or is there some other way to iterate over a dimension of a `Tensor`?

Comment: If you want to do a Python `for` loop and apply some Python function to each result, then you need to materialize results first into numpy array (using session run)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the new [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#map_fn), [`tf.foldl()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#foldl) [`tf.foldr()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#foldr) or (most generally) [`tf.scan()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#scan) higher-order operators, which were added to TensorFlow in version 0.8. The particular operator that you would use depends on the computation that you want to perform. For example, if you wanted to perform the same function on each row of the tensor and pack the elements back into a single tensor, you would use `tf.map_fn()`:

```
p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 100])

def f(x):
    # x will be a tensor of shape [None, 100].
    return tf.reduce_sum(x)

# Compute the sum of each [None, 100]-sized row of `p`.
# N.B. You can do this directly using tf.reduce_sum(), but this is intended as 
# a simple example.
result = tf.map_fn(f, p)
```

Comment: This does help a bit, but it still doesn't solve my problem. The reason I want to iterate over the list is because output of my first row might affect some other row, not just the next row.  Can I convert it to list at run time?

Comment: You can't convert it to a list at runtime. You could probably achieve what you're trying to do with `tf.foldl()` or `tf.scan()`, as these let you accumulate some state between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your input in as a single tensor `x` of shape [None, None, 10] and then use `tf.split(0, -1, x)` to get a list of tensors that you can iterate over.

Comment: But that will also result in a tensor ,right?  So how I iterate over it?

Comment: Nope, tf.split returns a list not a tensor.

Comment: Unfortunately, because `tf.split()` returns a list at graph construction time, the `num_split` argument must be an integer greater than zero, so I don't think this will work.